# How can I position the navbar on the right hand side of the screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can i put a nav that uses half of the screen on the left side and that on the right side i can scroll down without the nav moving
What I'm trying to get is something like the images that I'm going to put:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbwCV.png)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZG59.png)

I tried using `position: sticky;` for the `nav` and using `flex-direction: column;` for the right hand column but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most efficient ways to solve this is the usage of a 2-column grid. As a direct child of the grid container (body in this case), you use an `aside` element and a `main` element as the main content.

Within the `aside` you can place the `nav` and use `position: sticky; top: 0;` to keep the navbar within the viewport.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* for visualisation purpose only */
main {
  min-height: 5000vh;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

nav {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <nav>This is the navbar</nav>
</aside>
<main>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

`position: fixed;` is probably what you are looking for. If you apply it to the nav, it will always stay where it is, even if you scroll. Be aware, that when you do that, other elements might end up behind the nav.

Also, it'd be very helpful, if you provided some code we could try. Without the code, this is the best I can do.

Comment: position: fixed will move the nav out of flow which can cause collisions with the remaining content. Besides that, Answers should not be sued to communicate with the OP and ask for further details. Missing reputation is no excuse to misuse the answer option as a workaround to your account limitations.

Comment: @tacoshy I believe position: fixed; is exactly what op is looking for, isn't it?

Comment: Like I said it would move the element out of flow. That can cause other issues. there are more elegant solutions than position: fixed.